# Getting runtime error - Automation error when sending e-mail in excel using gmail

Tags: excel, email, cdo.message

hello i tried to send email in excel

here is my code

```
    Sub send_email_via_Gmail()
Dim myMail As CDO.Message

Set myMail = New CDO.Message

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = "smtp.gmail.com"

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 587

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = "example@gmail.com"

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = "password"

myMail.Configuration.Fields.Update

With myMail
.Subject = "Test Email from Dr. Takyar"
.From = "example@gmail.com"
.To = "example1@gmail.com"

.TextBody = "Good morning!"

End With

myMail.Send
MsgBox ("Mail has been sent")
Set myMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

but when i run this it is giving me runtime error
when i try to send mail.. 
for me coding seems correct .. i dont know what is the issue .. 
please help

Comment: Have you added CDO reference to your project?

Comment: If I remember correctly, the last time I tested a CDO program that used the same gmail address for the *To* and *From*, I received an error. As soon as I sent from one address to another it went away. I would recommend checking that first.

Comment: yes i have added CDO reference to my project

Comment: i have added different _to_ and _from_ but still  i am getting same error.

Comment: Have you tried on port 465 (instead of 587)?

Comment: yeahh.. thnx... it works for me